# Spring boot session timeout issue after upgrading from 0.5.0.M7 to 1.1.9.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am seeing strange issue after upgrading spring boot from 0.5.0.M7 to 1.1.9.RELEASE.
My application.properties has this property defined

---

```
server.session-timeout=60
```

But now my session gets expired within 1 minute of inactivity. I switch back to previous version and the issue disappears.

I debugged my code to see if ServerProperties.java was setting 60 to sessionTimeout variable inside it. And it indeed did.

Can somebody point me to the direction I should be looking to? What has changed that could cause such an issue?

Comment: What other input shall I provide in order to get help from community?

Comment: Did you needed any configurations? Or did you just added server.session-timeout into properties file? Is this calculation the inactive time or starts when the the session is created?

Comment: This is basically related to your servlet container session timeout config. In my case its tomcat and it calculates the inactive time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix
The following documentation contains all the properties that you can use in you yml configuration. Here is what it says about the server.session-timeout:

```
server.session-timeout= # session timeout in seconds
```

If you want to have 60 minutes timeout then you need to use

```
server.session-timeout=3600
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That might make sense. But this brings me to think, how did it work before that? Did the spring guys change it from minutes to seconds? This thread talks about minutes for the earlier version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561915/spring-boot-spring-security-session-timeout

Comment: Indeed. someone is saying that this is in seconds, someone is saying in minutes. I would rely on the official documentation and that your server is timing out after the specified period in seconds

Comment: @hellojava That's the sort of change you should expect when going from a prerelease 0.x milestone to a major GA release.

Comment: It was a bug in Spring Boot. It was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/0c0a0a7738121229a2c470be0b6f8fd8e7061d27)