# Springboot app session timeout

Tags: java, spring-boot, session-timeout

I have created a SpringBoot MVC/Security app 1.2.2.RELEASE and my application.properties contains server settings like

```
#Tomcat port and contextPath details
server.port=8080
server.contextPath=/test
#server.session-timeout=120
server.sessionTimeout=120
```

The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties-security) states

```
server.session-timeout= # session timeout in seconds
```

but the [ServerProperties.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java) uses sessionTimeout;

If you look at the application.properties code I have posed, I have tried both independently and together, but I don't get timed out after 2 minutes, I don't have any other code explicitly written to perform any session handeling.

Has anyone come across this issue? What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Boot's [relaxed binding](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) means that both `server.sessionTimeout` and `server.session-timeout` will configure `ServerProperies`' `sessionTimeout` property. Note that the unit is seconds, not minutes.

Comment: @Andy, thanks for the information, but that still does not explain why I don't get a time out, even if I set the value to 120 sec (2 minutes)

Comment: That's why it's a comment rather than an answer

Comment: According to this, the timeout is not expressed in number of minutes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561915/spring-boot-spring-security-session-timeout

Comment: Why would you get a timeout? The session will be cleaned up, if you are mixing this with Spring Security (not apparent from your question) it might be that that is configured wrongly. Also the timeout is ~ 2 minutes, depending on when the reaper thread is running, instead of 2 minutes it could actually be 3 minutes depending on the thread cleaning up the sessions.

Comment: @victor did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 10):

I don't know for some reason only setting

```
server.session.timeout=120
```

didn't work for me however, when I set both session timeout and cookie max age like below:

```
server.session.cookie.max-age=120
server.session.timeout=120
```

it works perfectly

Comment: it works because browser invalidates the cookie and doesn't send it to the server, therefore the server can't find the session

Comment: This way, the cookie gets invalidated, regardless of activity, therefore, you may be logged out while you are filling a form, and by the time you submit, you will be redirected.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what this server.session.timeout is for because when I set it to a specific number, and monitor the session creation, the session expiry does not get changed.

I'm using spring session and redis integration, in my case, I need to set the maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds to be like 120(seconds), this can be done thru redisHttpSessionConfiguration.

And then if I go to redis to look for the session, I can see it's expiry is changed to 120 seconds and session timeout works.

One suggestion of mine would be that try to find out if you can configure the session's maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds(or similar) either programmatically or in the property file and monitor session changes.

Answer (score 2):

(This applies to Spring 1.5.x at the time of this writing)

Note that if you're using **Redis session @EnableRedisHttpSession** (such as in the other comment [@Phoebe Li's case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44461990/756076)), then the application property server.session won't be applied. You'll have to set it manually by code like this:

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig {
    @Bean
    public RedisOperationsSessionRepository sessionRepository(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
        RedisOperationsSessionRepository sessionRepository = new RedisOperationsSessionRepository(factory);

        //Set the TTL of redis' key, which in turn will expire session when TTL is reached
        sessionRepository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(15); //e.g. 15 seconds

        return sessionRepository;
    }I
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In application.yml of my Spring Boot 2 app

```
# A negative value means that the cookie is not stored persistently and will be deleted when the Web browser exits
server:
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        max-age: -1
      timeout: -1
```

With these settings `JSESSIONID` cookie expiration time is set to "When the browsing session ends".

Answer (score 0):

You can try with adding this both statements.

```
server.session.cookie.max-age=120
server.session.timeout=120
```

You can find complete example on my blog here: http://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/spring-boot/how-to-set-spring-boot-tomcat-session-timeout.html