# Server.session.timeout doesn't work in spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-session

I have an issue with configuring default time for session timeout in Spring Boot app. I have the following in my `applicaion.properties`:

```
datasource.program_management.driverClass=org.postgresql.Driver
datasource.program_management.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/db
datasource.program_management.username=username
datasource.program_management.password=pass

logging.level.appName = DEBUG

server.session.timeout=30
```

However, this doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: And what makes you think it doesn't work...

Comment: I can call the endpoint from my web app, and it returns proper values, instead of 403's (forbidden)

Comment: How are you deploying it? In embedded container or in standalone Tomcat?

Comment: And what type of authentication are you using... Form, Basic...

Comment: Looks like you have the same issue as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128277/springboot-app-session-timeout