# Disable multiple logins for same user in spring security + spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I have the below Spring Security configuration:

```java
static SessionRegistry SR;
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/forgotPwd", "/resetPwd").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .permitAll()
            .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler) // autowired or defined below
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessHandler(myLogoutSuccessHandler)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .sessionRegistry(SR);
}

@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}
```

I was expecting `sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1)` to disable multiple login for the same user. It is working, but first user `logout` the application, so I am trying login in another browser but it showing `This account is already using by someone`.

Kindly request you to let me know where its going wrong.

Comment: To clarify, do you want the first session to be invalidated?

Comment: @Pär Nilsson:Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `httpSessionEventPublisher` and `SessionRegistry`

Try this config:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
      .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/", "/forgotPwd", "/resetPwd").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
      .formLogin()
         .loginPage("/login")
         .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
         .failureUrl("/login?error")
         .permitAll()
         .and()
      .sessionManagement()
         .maximumSessions(1);
}
```

You can set the session timout in the `application.properties`

```
server.session.timeout= # Session timeout in seconds.
```

Comment: i solved it, i am getting null values in `sessionregistory`, now how to implement session timeout in my code?

Comment: You can set it in `aplication.properties` see my edit

Comment: Not working i tried `server.session.timeout` and `server.session-timeout`

Comment: are you using an embedded server/container?

Comment: embedded server, spring boot have tomcat default na?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to invalid user session on logout with and/or delete cookies if you have one.

```
.logout().deleteCookies(...).invalidateHttpSession(true)
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `deleteCookies(...)`

Comment: Check if there are any cookies which are created on login in. If there are, just remove them. First try to add 'invalidHttpSession'.

Comment: Just now i closed the tab without `logout`. And trying to `login` in another browser but not `logging`

Comment: @Druga https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272137/how-to-end-sessions-automatically-if-user-closes-the-browser

Comment: but i am not using `.xml` files. i am using spring boot

Comment: @Druga it is the same but just put it in Application Properties https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128277/springboot-app-session-timeout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145013/discussion-between-durga-and-rjiuk).