# Spring boot security avoid specific user session expire

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, session-management

Hello everyone I've got my spring boot application on Apache Tomcat server and it works fine. But now I need to avoid session expiration for an specific user. How could I do that? I've been searching ways and found that handler interceptor could be useful for session management but I'm not sure.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Why* do you want to avoid session expiration?

Comment: It's a client requeriment. They want to avoid session expiration for an specific user.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504590/how-can-i-use-spring-security-without-sessions OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561915/spring-boot-spring-security-session-timeout OR http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session

Comment: Regardless of whether or not it's a requirement, *why* would one want to not have a user session expire?  If that user has any sort of power, that's a *significant* security hole.

Comment: Not exacty, I don't want to dismiss sessions at all, I just want to prevent a specific user to expire its session. Thansk anyway

Comment: Makoto you got a point in that but I need to do this, could you guide me to do it?

Comment: Not until you explain ***why***.  This has the symptoms of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no simple way to do it. Expiration timeout is common for all users of your application and controlled by the application server. In order to have a different timeouts for different users you should:

1. implement some session wrapper over a native server session;
2. set expiration timeout for native server sessions to the longest time that you will give to one of your user sessions;
3. manage expiration timeout of your session wrappers by your own.

**EDIT:** In my opinion the best way to solve this issue is reconsidering of client's requirement (immortal user with admin rights is a bad idea for your application). Anyway customizing of security related parts of application is always risky and you should really know what you do.

Comment: Personally I'd recommend not answering until we have more insight into the rationale.  Your advice is sound and something I'd be saying, but the deeper issue of "why" still persists.

Comment: @Makoto I agree, this is a strange requirement that can lead to a breach in application security. I'll edit my answer respectively.